# LTC3588-1 circuit model LTSpice export

Tags: voltage-regulator, ltspice

I would like to use the LTC3588-1 component native to LTSpice in SIMetrix, however I am struggling to find a way to handle the export/import.

Is it possible to export a component from LTSpice in a format that can be interpreted by SIMetrix, or other simulation software (i.e. a .MOD file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models in LTspice have, in general, a SPICE-compatible format. If you find a model in LTspice, open it up with a text-viewer (*not* Notepad, one that handles Unix endlines), and check the syntax. If it doesn't have LTspice specific elements, such as A-devices, for example, then you should be good to go. The only thing that remains to check is whether if it actually works in SIMETRIX.

If, OTOH, the file is encrypted -- which happens to be the case here -- you're out of luck, since encryption only works for the software that generated them. You can check if it's encrypted by looking in `My Documents/LTspiceXVII/lib/sub/LTC3588-1.sub`. The extensions do not matter (at least in LTspice they don't), since the `.inc` or `.lib` command accepts full paths. I don't have SIMETRIX but I don't think they work any differently (if I'm wrong, let me know).

Comment: I see, when I open the .sub file in Sublime Text I can can see it is in hex. It is a shame that it isn't accessible. They aren't [willing to share](https://ez.analog.com/power/f/q-a/106395/ltc3588-1-model-file) it either

Comment: @Jarvis Most probably it's what they consider proprietary information, nothing anyone can do about that.